# Create a automated backup of database to ftp server using php code

Tags: php, sql, ftp

Needed to create automated backup of sql file to a ftp server.

Below mentioned code i am using for the same

```
    function backup_db()
    {
    ini_set('memory_limit','100G');
        ini_set('max_input_time', 3000000);  
        ini_set('max_execution_time', 3000000);
        error_reporting(E_ALL);
        ini_set('display_errors', 1);

        //echo 'here';exit;  
        $this->load->dbutil();
        $this->load->helper(array('file', 'download')); 

        $prefs = array(
                'tables'      => array(),   // Array of tables to backup.
                'ignore'      => array('general_ledger'),           // List of tables to omit from the backup
                'format'      => 'zip',             // gzip, zip, txt
                'filename'    => 'mybackup.sql',    // File name - NEEDED ONLY WITH ZIP FILES
                'add_drop'    => TRUE,              // Whether to add DROP TABLE statements to backup file
                'add_insert'  => TRUE,              // Whether to add INSERT data to backup file
                'newline'     => "\n"               // Newline character used in backup file
              );


        //$this->db->save_queries = false;
        $backup = $this->dbutil->backup($prefs);
        //echo "in";exit();
        $filename = 'backup-' . date('d_m_Y_H_i_s') . ' .zip';

        write_file('/opt/backups/' . $filename, $backup);
        //force_download($filename, $backup); 



    try{
    $ftp_server = "xyz.xyz.xyz.xyz"; //server Ip
    $ftp_conn = ftp_connect($ftp_server);
    $ftp_username = "user";
    $ftp_userpass = "pass";

    $login = ftp_login($ftp_conn, $ftp_username, $ftp_userpass);

    // open file for reading
    $file = "/opt/backups/".$filename;
    $fp = fopen($file,"r");

    // upload file
    $success=ftp_fput($ftp_conn, "/Live_db_backups/Backup/$filename", $fp, FTP_ASCII);

    // close this connection and file handler
    ftp_close($ftp_conn);
    fclose($fp);
}catch (Exception $e) {
$this->session->set_flashdata('error',"FTP Error for Db backup File Download!!!!");
echo 'FTP Bachup Failed';
}

      echo 'here';  exit;
    }
```

What actually happening in this code is only half of the database backup is being stored.

Complete database backup is not getting saved to a file.

Tried with increasing `ini_set('memory_limit','100G');
            ini_set('max_input_time', 3000000);

            ini_set('max_execution_time', 3000000)`

But still only half of the db value is storing.

What may be the issue?.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Did you get any error in script?

Comment: No error in php script

Comment: No error in php script

Comment: May not be your immediate problem, but you absolutely cannot upload .zip file using FTP ascii transfer mode (`FTP_ASCII`).

Comment: Also your question title fails to describe your problem. - You simply seem to have problem with finishing an upload of a large file to FTP server. - For that over a half of your code and [tag:sql] tag are irrelevant. We need [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

ftp_connect has a time out parameter you can set
This is from the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-connect.php):

> timeout
>   This parameter specifies the timeout in seconds for all subsequent network operations. If omitted, the default value is 90 seconds. The timeout can be changed and queried at any time with ftp_set_option() and ftp_get_option().